# Why does the definite article for country names vary so much? (e.g. "no Brasil", "na Alemanha", "em Portugal")

Tags: artigos-definidos

In Portuguese, countries' names can be preceded by either masculine, feminine or no definite article. For example:

- "**O** Brasil fica na América do Sul"
- "**A** Alemanha fica na Europa"
- "**Portugal** também fica na Europa"

Why does this happen and what are the rules for which is which?

Comment: This happens in all dialects and variants of Portuguese, AFAIK.

Comment: This is one of the most interesting questions here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This seems to happen for no other reason than it sounds more natural for native speakers for no specific, definable reason.**

As Fernando correctly pointed out, it's not the gender that varies. In Portuguese, all nouns have a gender. What happens is that the definite article can be omitted in some cases.

The names by which speakers of a language call stuff whose proper name is in another language (for example, country, city names, etc) are called **exonyms** (*exônimos*).

The genders of exonyms follow basically the same general gender rules as any other noun. For example, most words ending in *-a* are feminine, and so is **Alemanha**. Both *civil* and *perfil* are masculine, and so is **Brasil**. *Hospital, local* and *natal* are masculine, and so is **Portugal**.

The question remains, though: why do we omit the definite article for words seemingly so similar? (e.g. *Passarei **o** natal **em** Portugal).

But there seems to be no definite answer to that. Here is a statement from Prof. Sérgio Nogueira, a well-known teacher of the Portuguese language:

> A maioria dos nomes de países exigem o artigo: a Argentina, o Brasil, a Alemanha, o Peru, a Espanha, o Uruguai... Mas há um bom número que rejeita o artigo: Israel, Portugal, Cuba, Angola, Moçambique, Cabo Verde...

Source: [G1 - Quais cidades, estados brasileiros e países pedem artigo definido?](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/quais-cidades-estados-brasileiros-e-paises-pedem-artigo-definido.html)

And he concludes, not only on the matter of articles for countries, but also for cities and states:

> Como podemos constatar, não há propriamente uma regra.

Here is a [map from Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:G%C3%AAneros_de_nomes_de_pa%C3%ADses_em_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa.png) on the genders of articles in Portuguese. Green is masculine, Purple is feminine, yellow means article is omitted.

[image: Gêneros de nomes de países em língua portuguesa. Source: Wikimedia]

For non-native Portuguese speakers, I'm afraid the only way out is memorisation, and a developed sense of what sounds right over time. All evidence from my research points to the fact that *if* there is a rule, it's complex and/or obscure enough not to be taught as one.

*PS: After some research, and despite Fernando's answer, I decided to try my own answer.*

Comment: Rafael, your answer is far more explanatory than mine. I upvoted it, and I do believe your answer should be accepted instead of mine. (According to Stack Exchange Rules, accepted answer should be changed if a better one comes along).

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro actually, the thumb rule of accepting an answer is to choose the one that helped the OP the most, while still being useful to forthcoming visitors. Nevertheless, this answer is a better candidate indeed.

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro Thank you for the acknowledgement! I'll accept the suggestion then.  (Interesting coincidence, we're both from the same city and from the same line of work!)

Answer (score 14):

The article depends on the gender of the word. The article is sometimes ommited for countries, but the gender still exists. Sometimes the gender comes from classifications; cities are generally feminine; countries and states are generally masculine; but in some cases I see no reason or logic behind it.

In Brazil there is no "neutral" gender, so all nouns/substantives have a gender, which sometimes is arbitrary and can be confusing: "sea" is masculine in Portuguese, but feminine in Spanish. I don't know of a better way to know which gender is proper, other than to just memorize as you read more and more, or looking up the gender on dictionaries (`s.m.` and `s.f.` for "substantivo masculino" and "- feminino"). And thank God we do not write thousands of different small characters like Japanese and Chinese!

So Brazil is masculine, as most countries; Germany is feminine; United States is masculine (because state is masculine), but America and Europe are feminine. Actually all continents are feminine, so you get a break.

As you know, if it's feminine it should take the feminine article `a`, and if masculine it should take the masculine article `o`. But you can drop the article (as is common use in many cases) and use `em`. That is the problem. It may be considered "correct" if you write `em` when an article was expected, but it will be at least confusing.

São Paulo City, for instance, is usually referred to using `em`, as are most cities, but if you talk about the metropolitan region you say "n**a** grande São Paulo" (and the same applies to most cities). Rio de Janeiro, on the other hand, is masculine, probably because the word "Rio" is masculine, which means people will say "n**o** Rio de Janeiro".

About Portugal, it actually is masculine (as most countries), which means you can google (for instance) for "meu Portugal" (with quotes) and find a ton of stuff about Portugal.

It's just that common use is to drop the article.

The same actually happens with people's names. In the north-eastern region in Brazil (Bahia for example) it's common use to omit articles before people's names (so if I'm going to João's place, I would say "vou a casa **de** João"), while in the south-eastern region it is almost mandatory to use the article ("vou a casa **do** João"), despite formal Portuguese saying we should not put articles in front of people's names.

Comment: Where does formal Portuguese say you shouldn't put articles before proper names?

Comment: There are many issues in this answer: choose "male" and "female" rather than "boy" or "girl". "Vou a casa" rather than "Vou à casa". It could also use a general proof-read.

Comment: Falta só explicar o porquê de Alemanha ser menina, Estados Unidos menino e Portugal sem género.

Comment: -1: strong disagreement with `But you can drop the article (as is common use in many cases) and use em. That is the problem. It may be considered "correct" if you write em when an article was expected, but it will be at least confusing.` The answer's quality is still low, too, in my opinion.

Comment: @ANeves I added my own answer to try to address some shortcomings in this answer.

Comment: @E_net4, I have seen this taught referring to something having the genitalia for that gender, to make it easier to memorize. Sorry that you disagree but usually people pick it up better if you use more common words, and I'm not writing a dictionary, I'm explaining it as I think works best for most people that feel this is confusing. You should upvote Rafael's answer though, he did it "the right way". ;)

Comment: @ANeves, yup, it is low, I'm not the best and brightest in the world, but it's better to have some explanation than no explanation, and even though you disagree, it is a fact that you can drop the article for any "Nome Próprio" (So a person, country or whatever name), as you can confirm in http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/14/dode-paulo/

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro yeah, I'm not saying you should not have posted an answer at all. My greatest concern was that the answer could be of greater quality and yet the community went in favour of it.

Comment: @someonewithpc I couldn't finde a nicer/newer one to link to, so: https://goo.gl/4Hm1Ho (Full source: https://goo.gl/TuSF15). Although I do not suggest using "Gramáticas Normativas" as the best source since the newest one is like 100 years old, they are still the closest we have to a formal "reference guide" to Portuguese. But yeah, not that relevant, this stuff is dead anyways.

Comment: +0: It sounds weird to me to omit the article in "a casa do João", @FernandoCordeiro, but nevertheless I stand corrected; thanks!

Comment: @ANeves, sounds weird to me too, and I do believe if we accepted the existence of "Dialects" in Portuguese it would be much easier. The rules are mutating either way, which is why nobody publishes "Gramáticas Normativas" anymore. Linguists are trying to compromise between formality and mutability/evolution.

Answer (score -2):

Our teacher told us country names of Portugal and its former colonies do not have articles. All other countries have.

Comment: That sounds like a good general rule, but does not work for Israel and Cuba. Also, it would be good to have a source for that.

Comment: Another counter example is Brazil, which is a former Portuguese colony, but almost always has the definite article (at least in Brazilian Portuguese).