# Is there a general rule for using articles before proper nouns?

Tags: gramática

The definite article (*o* or *a*) is included or omitted from proper nouns. Many include countries, but other proper nouns carry this as well.

A simple example:

- o Brasil - *Vou para **o** Brasil*
- China - *Vou para China*

Is there a general rule? Perhaps a guideline?

### Expansion

Just to expand on this question a bit, I'll use some more nouns (that aren't countries), but I'm not sure which one is right:

- Usei PHP e MySQL / Usei *o* PHP e *o* MySQL
- Conversei com Daniele / Conversei com a Daniele
- Assisti *Divertida Mente* ontem, foi bem legal / Assisti *a* *Divertida Mente* ontem, foi bem legal

... etc.

Comment: Quite similar to another question, but the accepted answer is poor: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/202/why-does-the-definite-article-for-country-names-vary-so-much-e-g-no-brasil

Comment: "Vou para Brasil" sounds really strange, it really needs the article. On the other hand, "Vou para o São Paulo" looks very wrong for me, it should not have the article. So, nice question, and sorry for not knowing the answer. I will upvote this question as soon as possible (not now because I already spent all my votes for today).

Comment: @E_net4 I didn't see that question -- we can consider marking this a duplicate. I attempted to ask the question in a general way, as I'd like to know about other proper nouns -- I'll edit to expand.

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar Yes, I wouldn't mind you editing the question, hopefully in order to obtain a high-quality answer.

Comment: @VictorStafusa I hope you agree with me that we should not base our answers on how strange they sound. In most cases, there is _one_ correct  form, and that's it.

Comment: @E_net4 I can appreciate your sentiment, but at the same time I understand VictorStafusa's comment -- many times when my wife has asked me questions about English, my only *honest* answer was *"It doesn't feel right"* :P

Comment: @E_net4 Surely, this is precisely the reason that I wrote a comment instead of an answer, because I can't explain it.

Comment: *China* also takes an article, we say *Vou para a China*, ou *Vou à China*.

Comment: Short answer is **no**. You have to learn which nouns require the article  by experience, just like you learn the gender of the nouns.

Comment: @bfavaretto Should I then ask questions such as, "Do I use the definite article with the proper noun *MySQL*?", "Do I use the definite article when referring to a movie title?", etc. etc. ?

Comment: There may be some general rules, I'll look into it. But I bet none of them is bullet-proof.

Comment: "Assisti _a_ Divertida Mente ontem (...)." is the correct form, however _a_ is not a determinant, in this case - it's a preposition.

Comment: Funny to say that "Vou pra China" is correct, meanwhile "Vou para China" is not. This is because "pra" is a contraction of "para + a" and "pro" is to "para + o". It's probably difficult for a foreign to distinguish "pra" and "para" while hearing it, but believe me that they are way different from each other.

Comment: @Math Deve ser por isso que pensei que *Vou para China* estava correta - consigo ouvir a diferença entre *para* e *pra*, mas não sabia que *pra* era uma conjunta de duas palavras - apenas uma abreviação de *para*.

Comment: Hum.. let me think a bit more about what I said, perhaps that is just partially true :P I guess that sometimes "pra" is also a short way to say "para", without the contraction of "a". But "vou pra China" still seems totally fine for me.

Comment: Related: [Quando usar “Pra” ou “Para”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/579/3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably searching for **definite article** (*artigo definido*) and its uses.

## Definite Article Guidelines (*Dicas para Artigo Definido*)

[The Brazilian Federal Senate has this Guideline that can be useful](http://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/artigo-definido).

[Another good source is this site](http://www.gramaticaonline.com.br/page.aspx?id=9&iddetalhe=116&idsubcat=35&idcateg=3).

### 1 - General Use

a) individualizes the noun: *O marido, a mulher e os filhos compareceram à festa. / Aquele era o dono da empresa*.

b) Emphasizes a unique situation: *Não era um jornalista; era o jornalista*.

c) precedes the names of literary and artistic works (if the item is part of the name, will be in capitals): *Gostava mais do Quincas Borba que das Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas. / Preferia Os Lusíadas às Memórias do Cárcere*.

d) particularizes names of things (buildings, vehicles, ships, etc.) and the agreement is made ​​with the idea expressed by the thing: *a (nave) Challenger, o (porta-aviões) Minas Gerais, o (prédio) Martinelli, o (edifício) Joelma, o (navio) Ana Néri, o (remédio) AZT.*

e) expresses the singular to plural idea of a genre, category, group or substance: *O tamoio aliou-se ao francês, no Rio. / "O sertanejo é antes de tudo um forte."*

f) With pronominal function prevents an ambiguous meaning: *Entre o exército brasileiro e o argentino.* The second *o* makes it clear that these are two armies and not one made ​​up of Brazilian and Argentine simultaneously.

### 2 - With possessive

a) It is optional to use the article before possessive accompanying a noun: *meu carro, o meu carro; sua casa, a sua casa; prejudicar nossa viagem, prejudicar a nossa viagem.* For many authors, with the omission of the article the phrase gains in lightness. Thus, *Sua mãe, seu pai e seu irmão cantam bem* has more pace than *A sua mãe, o seu pai e o seu irmão cantam bem.*

b) use the article the possessive is isolated and if you want to particularize the statement: *Esta casa é a minha. / Todos devem zelar pelo nome dos seus.*

c) Do not use the article when the possessive belongs to a formula of treatment is part of a vocative or equivalent to some, many: *Recorro a (e não à) Vossa Senhoria. / Nossa Senhora chorava. / Veja, meu amigo, quanta maldade. / Todos temos nossos defeitos.*

d) Also it don't have article expressions as *em minha opinião, a meu ver, a seu ver, em meu poder, em nossas mãos, a seu bel-prazer, por vossa vontade, por meu mal, algo de seu, muito de meu, etc.*

e) The article replaces possessive when used before the name body parts, clothing, personal effects, the spirit colleges and kinship relations: *Mexeu os braços (e não os seus braços). / Passou a mão pelos cabelos. / Vestiu a camisa e as calças. / Colocou os óculos, a capa e o chapéu, e saiu. / Lembrava-se remotamente do pai.*

### 3 - With geographical names

a) It is used usually the item with the names of countries, regions, continents, mountains, volcanoes, deserts, constellations, rivers, lakes, oceans, seas and islands groups: *o Brasil, os Estados Unidos, a Antártida, a Baixada Santista, a Europa, os Alpes, os Andes, o Vesúvio, o Saara, o Cruzeiro do Sul, a Ursa Maior, o Tietê, o Titicaca, o Atlântico, o Mediterrâneo, os Açores.* Exception: Some countries and regions, however, do not accept the article: *Portugal, Angola, Moçambique, Cabo Verde, São Tomé e Príncipe, Macau, Timor, Andorra, Israel, Aragão e Castela.*

b) Do not use the definite article, in general, with the names of towns, villages and most of the islands: *São Paulo, Visconde de Mauá, Malta, Cuba.* Exception: City names that are formed from common nouns retain Article: *o Recife, o Rio de Janeiro, o Porto, o Havre, o Cairo.* Some islands also keep the article: *a Córsega, a Sicília, a Sardenha, a Madeira, a Groenlândia.*

c) With respect to Brazilian states, there are some who admit the article and others do not.

d) Do not use the article in general, with planets and stars names: *Urano, Plutão, Sírius, Canópus*. Exceptions: *a Terra e o Sol*.

e) The cardinal and collateral points require paper (even when designating winds): *"São os do Norte que vêm." / A caravana dirigia-se para o sul. / Está soprando o noroeste*. When only indicates direction, dispense the article: *Vento de leste. / Caminhadas de norte a sul*.

f) There is article when you qualify or determine a geographical name: *Visitei a Roma do Coliseu. / Era a estratégica Malta. / Morei no São Paulo dos cafezais (Estado). / Mudou-se para a São Paulo da garoa (cidade)*.

### 4 - With names

a) Do not use the product when it comes to famous figures, people with whom they are not familiar and names of saints: *Admirava Joana d'Arc. / Chegou com Maria. / Era devota de Santo Antônio*. ExceptionÇ There is article when referring to the party referring to the saint: *Assisti ao melhor São João da minha vida*.

b) Use the article to indicate intimacy with the person, determining a first and last name or qualifier of people: *Andava sempre com o João. / Admirava o Napoleão conquistador. / Ali estava o Barbudo. / Descendia de Isabel, a Redentora*. Exception: *Frederico Barba-Roxa*.

### 5 - With titles and pronouns treatment

a) It is used in the article titles that indicate profession, position or condition: *o professor João Carlos, o general Ernesto Geisel, o doutor Pereira da Cunha, a escritora Lygia Fagundes Telles*.

b) Use the article with the words "senhor", "senhora" and "senhorita": *O senhor João dos Santos morreu ontem. / Falou com a senhora baronesa. / Perguntou pela senhorita Maria*. Do not use the article, however, when addressing the person: *Adeus, senhor Antônio*.

c) Do not use the article before "frei", "Sr" and "Monsignor" and before the titles and designations of foreign origin, as "madame", "Lord", "sir", "lady", etc .: *Era frei Ambrósio que chegava. / Falou com dom Luciano. / Conhecia monsenhor Vicente. / Casou-se com madame Claude. / Os ingleses encantam-se com lady Diana*.

d) Do not use the article before forms of treatment initiated by possessive: *Entrego o livro a Vossa Excelência. / Ali estava Sua Alteza*.

### 6 - Special cases

a) In the enumerations, the use of the article depends on whether or not it is a particular instance: *O Brasil, a Argentina e o Uruguai debateram a dívida externa* (specified). */ Falava corretamente português, italiano e francês* (not specified).

b) When used with a noun in a series, the article should be used for others: *O Brasil, a Argentina e o Uruguai discutiram... *, not *O Brasil, Argentina e Uruguai discutiram...*

c) You can use the article only with the first noun, assuming that the other presenting a closely linked set: *Para sua tese, recolheu as histórias, mitos, superstições e provérbios correntes na região*.

d) When it comes to different things expressed by the same noun, repeat the article; when it comes to the same thing, do not: *Apoiava o antigo e o atual governo. / O goleiro dominava a pequena e a grande área. / Tinha o vago, mas persistente sentido da morte. / Ouviram a nova e discutível versão da música. / Deu-lhe a triste ou melancólica notícia*.

e) The repetition of the article emphasizes the sentence: *Era o mesmo, o verdadeiro, o inigualável Anselmo*.

f) Superlatives sequences that require repetition: *Era o mais competente, o mais culto e o mais premiado dos repórteres do jornal. / Ali estava a maior, a melhor e a mais bela modelo do país*.

### 7 - Article Omission

a) Journalistically, the definite article is often ommited in headlines: *Agora, governo usa inflação que quiser. / Brasil repele acusações de imperialismo.*

b) Keep the article, however, in headlines with superlatives or words of absolute sense: *Ministro diz que Brasil é o país mais protecionista. / Cai o último invicto*.

c) With the participles and the intransitive verbs placed before the subject, always use the article: *Desconhecido o paradeiro do menino. / Acusado o ministro da Fazenda. / Chega hoje o presidente da França*.

### 8 - Do not use the article

a) In proverbs, short comparisons, judgments and before general and indeterminate sense of nouns: *Amor com amor se paga. / Vermelho como sangue. / Tempo é dinheiro. / Cortesia impõe cortesia. / Criança tem mais disposição que adulto.*

b) When employing the verb to be for a definition: *"Política é a arte do possível"*. If the verb other, there is no definition and then an article is used: *A política trata... / A medicina busca recursos...*.

c) In vocatives, *Que quer, homem? / Ande logo, irmão.*

d) With expressions such as smell, know, ask forgiveness, beg, do penance, declare war, hear Mass, give alms, etc .: *Isto cheira a rosas. / A bebida sabe a vinho. / O país declarou guerra aos vizinhos. / O filho pediu perdão ao pai*.

e) Before the words house, land (opposing board, which also dispenses the article) and Palace: *Veio de casa. / Foi para casa. / Avistou terra. / Desceu a terra. / Gritou de bordo. / O senador foi chamado a palácio. / O presidente ainda estava em palácio*. There is article if has clear sense of determination: *Voltou à casa dos pais. / Avistou a terra desejada. / Não conhecia o Palácio dos Bandeirantes*.

f) After "whose": *Era o homem cujo pai (e nunca cujo o pai) procurávamos*.

g) To repeatedly with the superlatives as the most: *Eram os profissionais "os mais" competentes*. There are three possible ways (prefer the first one): *Eram os profissionais mais competentes. / Eram os mais competentes profissionais. / Eram profissionais os mais competentes.*

h) Before words for the field of study: *Lecionava matemática. / Estudava português*.

i) When words (and its synonyms) as time, motive, opportunity, opportunity, occasion, mood, strength, valor and courage (to something) are associated with verbs like be, have, miss, give, ask and equivalent: *Não tive tempo para sair. / Pediu nova oportunidade para provar sua competência. / Faltou-lhe ânimo (ou disposição) para enfrentar o desafio. / Pedimos permissão para ficar*.

[Translated from here](http://www.estadao-escola.com.br/manualredacao/esclareca/artigodefinido.shtm).

Comment: Quite an exhaustive answer, thank you @Cigano !

Comment: I'll wait another day or so to verify that no one else wants to answer at an attempt on the bounty

Comment: No problem. I'll edit it in the next days. Now I'm just exhausted for that.