# Quando usar "Pra" ou "Para"?

Tags: ortografia

Quando usar *"pra"* e quando usar *"para"*?

Ex: *"Pra você"* ou *"Para você"*?

As duas formas são corretas?

Comment: Pensei que já tivessem feito está pergunta, por isso nem pergunta. +1 acredito ser uma boa duvida :)

Comment: Procurei e não achei nada.

Comment: Eu sei, não foi o que eu quis dizer. É que é uma daquelas perguntas que todos pensamos, mas quando fui ver ninguém ainda tinha perguntado, por isso o +1 porque achoque é uma pergunta muito útil e lhe dou os parabéns por lembrar dela. Espero que tenha ficado claro :)

Answer (score 9):

#### Português de Portugal

Apenas a palavra *para* é formalmente correta. No português de  Portugal, *pra* (eventualmente escrita *pr'a* ou *p'ra*) apenas é utilizada como uma abreviação informal, tendencialmente falada, da palavra *para*. A contração de *para* com o artigo definido *a* não se aplica, ao contrário do que acontece no português do Brasil (como indicado [na outra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/580/84)).

Answer (score 7):

#### Português do Brasil

- **As duas formas estão corretas?**
  Sim. As duas formas estão corretas.
- **Quando usar *"Pra"* e quando usar *"Para"*?**
  O mais recomendável é usar **pra** apenas em linguagem falada e informalmente.

Segundo o site [dicio.com](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/para-ou-pra/)

> "Pra" pode ser também a forma contraída da preposição "para" com o artigo definido feminino "a" (para + a = pra). Não deverá ser acentuado com acento agudo, nem com acento grave, nem deverá ser escrito com apóstrofe.

Comment: Sinta-se a vontade para editar a resposta @E_net4

Comment: @E_net4, Por favor, nos diga qual o uso correto em Portugal dessas duas palavras.

Comment: Estive um pouco ocupado, lamento. Acrescentei uma resposta.

Comment: Ao que eu saiba, também não é correto no português do Brasil. "Pra" se usa em linguagem informal, mas isso não significa que seja correto - como também é usado em Portugal na linguagem informal sem ser, de acordo com a menção de @E_net4. Veja http://revistalingua.com.br/textos/blog-abizzocchi/qual-e-o-correto-pra-ou-pra-304098-1.asp

Comment: Parece que estamos perante um conflito entre dicionários.

Comment: @E_net4 sim, mas eu tenderia a dar mais peso ao endereço que coloquei porque o autor me parece qualificado para falar sobre o assunto. No site dicio.com não existe menção do autor. Veja também http://revistalingua.com.br/textos/blog-abizzocchi/aldo-bizzocchi-253207-1.asp