# "O que precisas?", "Do que é que precisas?"

Tags: regência-verbal

Quais das seguintes formas estão correctas, e se mais do que uma está, qual a diferença?

1. O que precisas?
2. O que é que precisas?
3. De que precisas?
4. Do que precisas?
5. De que é que precisas?
6. Do que é que precisas?

Penso que as duas primeiras estão erradas, já que é errado dizer *‘O que te queixas?’, mas correcto dizer ‘Do que te queixas?’ (*queixar-se de*, *precisar de*)

Answer (score 7):

Tem vários assuntos na sua pergunta, vou tentar abordar cada um separadamente.

### Regência de *precisar*

Na norma culta, *precisar* pede objeto indireto com a preposição *de*, exceto se for seguido de um verbo no infinitivo. Isso portanto elimina seus exemplos (1) e (2), onde temos um objeto direto.

Porém o uso prático não é tão rigoroso; é bastante comum dizer *preciso de falar*, e, no Brasil, também é comum usar *precisar* com objeto direto, principalmente na fala.

### "É que"

O "é que" geralmente é usado para dar ênfase a uma ou outra parte da frase, o que é conhecido como [clivagem](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/construcao-clivada/21944) (Mira Mateus et al., 2003). Adaptando os seus exemplos, existe uma sutil diferença de sentido dependendo de onde a expressão é colocada:

> *É disso que eu preciso*
> <sup>(ênfase no objeto)</sup>

> *Disso é que eu preciso*
> <sup>(ênfase no verbo)</sup>

Ou seja, a existência do "é que" nos seus exemplos (5) e (6) não o tornam mais "certos" ou "errados" que o (3) e o (4). Eles servem apenas para enfatizar a pergunta (os dois últimos soam como se houvesse um "afinal" no início, como em *afinal, do que precisas?*)

### Definitude

A diferença entre os exemplos (3) e (4), bem como entre o (5) e o (6), é o uso ou não de um determinante definido. Ele pode causar diferenças de sentido em diversas circunstâncias, como se pode ver [nesta outra pergunta do site, sobre o uso do artigo com nomes próprios](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/366/is-there-a-general-rule-for-using-articles-before-proper-nouns). Para se ter uma ideia, a [Gramática de Usos do Português](http://www.editoraunesp.com.br/catalogo/9788539300808,gramatica-de-usos-do-portugues) (Moura Neves, 2. ed. 2005) dedica em torno de 50 páginas só a esse tema... O que posso dizer sobre os seus exemplos é que (hehe), no Brasil, a ausência do artigo definido daria um tom um pouco mais formal à frase; na fala, é muito mais comum usarmos "do que", enquanto na escrita o uso oscila entre "do que" e "de que".

Comment: Fiquei esclarecido em relação ao seu segundo ponto. Quanto ao primeiro ponto, não percebi se os exemplos (1) e (2) estão ou não correctos. Poderia incluir alguns exemplos que ilustrem o que escreveu? O seu terceiro ponto ficou um pouco vago. Sugere-me que eu o separe numa outra pergunta, ou o tente incluir na outra pergunta de que inseriu o link?

Comment: Eu fiquei a perceber o mesmo...

Comment: @SérgioPereira Eu não esqueci dos seus pedidos, mas estou sem tempo para complementar e fundamentar melhor minha resposta. Adiantando, apenas os seus exemplos 1 e 2 estão incorretos na norma culta, os demais estão corretos. Aviso quando melhorar a resposta ok?

Comment: @bfavaretto Claro!, sem pressa.

Comment: Uma resposta ao meu gosto. A diferença entre o "do que" e o "de que" é a mesma em Portugal, podes tirar a referência ao Brasil, mas pelo que vi por aí é melhor manter o "hehe". Então "preciso de falar" está errado? Da tua resposta resulta que "preciso falar" está correto, fiquei na dúvida se "preciso de falar" está mesmo errado.

Comment: @Sérgio Nos exemplos (1) e (2) o "o" inicial é um objeto direto, que não pode ser usado com "precisar". Fica mais claro se pensares na resposta à pergunta. "O que precisas?" "Preciso uma faca." Não é correto dizer-se "preciso uma faca". O que é correto é "preciso **de** uma faca". Logo a pergunta correta é "do que precisas?" ou, um nadinha mais formal, "de que precisas?" (Se o **de** aparece na resposta, também tem de aparecer na pergunta.)

Comment: @bfavaretto , tenho dúvidas acerca da regência de precisar, na norma culta: 1) Pode-se omitir o objeto indireto, certo? ("Preciso sim.") 2.A) O verbo auxiliar pode **não** estar no infinitivo? (Talvez algo como "Não precisam virem tão cedo.") 2.B) Se o verbo não estiver no infinitivo, deve-se também não usar o "de"?