# Seria correto dizer "necessariamente precisa"?

Tags: gramática, pleonasmo

Por exemplo, na frase

> Uma caixa não necessariamente precisa ser quadrada.

usar "necessariamente precisa" está gramaticalmente correto? Seria pleonasmo?

Comment: "Precisar de": ver **[FLiP - regência do verbo precisar](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1052)**.

Comment: @Centaurus Que curioso! Em Portugal, transitivo direto é o precisar-"indicar", e indireto o precisar-"ter necessidade de".

Comment: @ANeves  Não se assuste com isso.  As diferenças transatlânticas são muias.  Até mesmo no Brasil, que tem dimensões continentais, o vocabulário e a gramática usados no Rio Grande do Sul são diferentes do que se usa no Ceará ou no Amazonas.

Comment: @Centaurus a resposta na pergunta «[“O que precisas?”, “Do que é que precisas?”](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/677/o-que-precisas-do-que-%C3%A9-que-precisas)» contradiz isso, e diz que na norma culta precisa do "de" `exceto se for seguido de um verbo no infinitivo`. Sugiro que acrescentes uma resposta lá.

Comment: @ANeves  Veja a minha resposta [à pergunta] (http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/no-brasil-%C3%A9-gramaticalmente-correto-usar-o-verbo-precisar-como-transitivo-dir)   onde explico os usos de "precisar" e "precisar de" no Brasil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não me parece ser um pleonasmo. Dependendo do contexto, "não...necessariamente"  **dá mais clareza** ao que se deseja transmitir.

eg.

- "Vou por tudo numa caixa. Veja se tem uma caixa quadrada no depósito."
- "Não encontrei. Ela precisa ser quadrada?"
- "Não, não necessariamente."

compare com:

- "Vou por tudo numa caixa. Veja se tem uma caixa quadrada no depósito."
- "Não encontrei. Ela precisa ser quadrada?"
- "Não"
- "Então porque você pediu quadrada?"

"não necessariamente" significa que a preferência é pela quadrada mas, na sua falta, outra pode servir.  Já o simples "não" fica um pouco ambíguo. "não necessariamente" evita que você use uma explicação longa como "a quadrada é mais apropriada mas, não havendo uma, usaremos uma caixa de outro formato."

Comment: Não sei, mas não me convenceu completamente. Eu vejo a frase "Então porque você pediu quadrada?" bem nas duas formas que enunciaste.

Comment: @JorgeB. Na primeira fica implícito que a quadrada seria melhor.  Pelo menos é assim que eu entenderia naquele contexto.  Depende também um pouco da intonação que se dá a "necessariamente"

Answer (score 5):

Eu diria que é de facto um pleonasmo que dá um foco maior à ideia de necessidade do que um simples "precisa". Mas "precisar" já transmite a ideia de necessitar. O Aulete [define "precisar"](http://www.aulete.com.br/precisar) como:

> 1. Ter necessidade (de) ou ser (algo) necessário.

Geralmente, quando se diz que `A` precisa de `B` está a dizer-se que `B` é **necessário**, não que `B` é suficiente (tal como outras alternativas seriam) ou que simplesmente dava jeito; não se "precisa opcionalmente":

> A: Preciso de uma caixa quadradada.
>   B: Tenho aqui uma redonda.
>   A: És surdo ou quê?

Mas por vezes é razoável não interpretar alguém literalmente:

> A: Preciso de uma coisa do Pingo Doce [supermercado].
>   B: Eu vou agora passar pelo Lidl [outro supermercado], o que queres que te traga?
>   A: Não, preciso **mesmo**/**necessariamente** que seja do Pingo Doce.

Possível, mas esquisita. **Mesmo** fica muito melhor. Aqui B está a inferir que A 1) não precisa de facto de ir ao supermercado (apenas precisa de um produto de lá) e que 2) esse mesmo produto existe em outro supermarcado ao qual ele já vai de qualquer forma. Em reposta, A concede implicitamente 1), mas não 2).

Onde "precisar necessariamente" é mais usado é na negativa. Todos os 8 exemplos de `[lema="precisar"] "necessariamente"` no CETEMPúblico são na negativa:

> Quem vem aos nossos concertos gosta de música, não **precisa necessariamente** de conhecer as canções.

A ideia transmitida é diferente de um simples *não precisa*. O que a frase implica é que é expectável, ou talvez até recomendável, que se conheçam as canções, mas não é literalmente necessário.

Parece-me que a razão por que há esta maior latitude na negativa é o facto de que "não ser necessário" deixa muito espaço aberto: pode ser algo preferencial (a interpretação com necessariamente), pouco ou nada relevante (*não é preciso de todo*) ou não ter qualquer julgamento (*não é preciso*).

Answer (score 3):

**Precisar necessariamente** só em contextos muito particulares será pleonasmo. A razão é que **necessariamente** tem um significado de *necessidade absoluta* que normalmente não está presente em **precisar**. O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (DACL) define **necessariamente**:

> (1) Por ser absolutamente preciso ou necessário; por necessidade. = obrigatoriamente.
> (2) Como consequência lógica, natural ou inevitável em qualquer caso. = fatalmente, forçosamente, inevitavelmente.

Só quando o contexto der a *precisar* o significado de *precisar com necessidade absoluta* é que *precisar necessariamente* será pleonasmo. Por exemplo:

> Este esquentador precisa de pilha para funcionar.

A frase tal como está já indica que *precisa* significa precisar com necessidade absoluta. Logo acrescentar *necessariamente* seria pleonástico. Mas ser pleonástico não significa ser incorreto. A literatura está cheia de pleonasmos.

Agora *precisar* não é normalmente usado com este caráter de necessidade absoluta. Por exemplo:

> Não *precisamos necessariamente* de meter gasolina para chegar ao Porto. Só se fores a acelerar é que precisamos; se não fores a mais de cem à hora, não precisamos.
>
> Não *precisamos necessariamente* de levantar mais dinheiro; se formos jantar ao Ritz, precisamos; se formos à Tasca do Manel, o dinheiro que temos chega e sobra.

Nos casos anteriores *precisar* é sim ou sopas: ou é absolutamente necessário ou não é. Mas, possivelmente, na maioria dos usos, *precisar de alguma coisa* é usado com o significado de *ser desejável, bom, vantajoso, conveniente ter essa alguma coisa*. E isto é um uso perfeitamente legítimo. Diz o DACL em **precisar** (significados mais relevante; como de costume, as definições remetem para outras palavras que remetem para outras palavra, mas os exemplos esclarecem):

> (6) Ter, alguém ou alguma coisa, falta de algo necessário, seja concreto ou abstrato; ter carência de. = carecer de, necessitar de. *Precisava de dinheiro. Precisava de casa. Precisava de ajuda. A casa precisava de obras. O escritório precisava de arrumação. As árvores precisam de água.*
> (7) Ter, alguém, necessidade, precisão de alguma coisa. = Necessitar de. *Precisava de madrugar. Precisava de melhorar a sua imagem. Precisava que a loja abrisse mais cedo.*

Destes exemplos, só no caso das árvores é que há implicitamente uma necessidade absoluta: sem água as árvores morrem. Nos outros casos a necessidade não é absoluta, logo admite gradações: pode ser maior ou menor. Ou seja pode-se precisar muito ou pouco. E aqui pode-se dizer *preciso necessariamente* com o significado de *preciso muito*. Não é um pleonasmo. Na maioria das frases afirmativas será é uma [hipérbole](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hip%C3%A9rbole), ou exagero. Por exemplo, quando se diz

> *Preciso necessariamente* de começar a fazer exercício físico,

o que se quer dizer, é que é muito importante para nós começarmos a fazer exercício físico; não que exista uma necessidade absoluta. Mas se, como observa o Artefacto, *precisar necessariamente* aparece sobretudo na negativa, então nem sequer hipérbole é.

Agora há outra coisa que podemos querer considerar. **Necessitar** pode ser usado com o significado de **precisar**. Portanto se não é pleonasmo dizer *precisar necessariamente*, também não o é dizer **necessitar necessariamente** (*necessitar* não tem que ter o significado de necessidade absoluta). Mas ninguém, a não ser para efeito cómico, diria isto. Ora o que pode acontecer é que ao dizermos ou ouvirmos *precisar necessariamente* esteja presente na nossa mente a possibilidade de substituir *precisar* por *necessitar*, e que isso suscite na nossa mente um pouco da aversão que sentimos perante *necessitar necessariamente.* Portanto uma pessoa pode querer evitar *precisar necessariamente* simplesmente por uma questão de estilo. Afinal existem muitas alternativas:

> Não precisamos verdadeiramente de uma caixa quadrada. Não temos necessariamente que meter gasolina. Não é absolutamente necessário/preciso levantar mais dinheiro. Não é imperioso chegar ao Porto antes das oito horas. Preciso mesmo/muito/urgentemente de começar a fazer exercício físico. Ó meus xenhores, não havia nexexidade de uma resposta tão longa,  etc. etc.

Comment: A última frase é espetacular de tantas formas que precisa necessariamente de um voto positivo ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Que fique claro que as pessoas, opiniões e acontecimentos retratados nas frases ilustrativas são fictícios, e qualquer semelhança com a realidade será mera coincidência.

Answer (score 0):

isso depende do contexto, pois pode ter coisas necessárias para o cenário, então essa tal coisa é precisa sempre, ou seja, necessariamente sempre sera precisa essa tal coisa.