# No Brasil, é gramaticalmente correto usar o verbo "precisar" como transitivo direto?

Tags: português-brasileiro, transitividade-verbal

O verbo "precisar" tem várias definições<sup>1</sup>, das quais me interessa apenas a primeira:

> pre·ci·sar - verbo transitivo
>
> 1. **Ter precisão ou necessidade de.**
> 2. Determinar, indicar, calcular de um modo preciso, com exactidão.
> 3. Especializar, particularizar.
> 4. Não poder passar sem, não poder prescindir de. verbo intransitivo
> 5. Ter precisão de dinheiro e de tudo quanto é essencial à vida; ser pobre.
> 6. Carecer.

Em Portugal, a definição `1.` acima é sempre transitiva indireta, e precisa da preposição "de" entre si e o complemento.

Mas [num comentário numa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1282) deste site disseram-me que no Brasil esta definição é principalmente utilizada como transitiva direta - portanto, sem a preposição "de".

[A fonte que consultei](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1052) indica que `este uso como transitivo directo [é] desaconselhado por alguns gramáticos`:

> Há ocorrências, sobretudo no português do Brasil, da ausência da
>   preposição de (ex.: eu preciso mais trabalho, eu preciso trabalhar
>   mais), embora este uso como transitivo directo seja desaconselhado por
>   alguns gramáticos. A ausência da preposição é, no entanto, considerada
>   aceitável quando o complemento do verbo é uma oração completiva
>   introduzida pela preposição que (ex.: eu preciso [de] que haja mais
>   trabalho), mas esta omissão deve ser evitada em registos formais ou
>   cuidados, pois o seu uso não é consensual.

Então:

- No Brasil esta definição do verbo precisar é transitiva direta, ou transitiva indireta?
- Qual é a forma gramaticalmente correta, de um ponto de vista académico?
- E qual é a forma que é usada, na prática?

---

<sup>1</sup> "precisar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/precisar [consultado em 30-09-2015].

Comment: Eu acho que [esta pergunta já existe](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/677/o-que-precisas-do-que-%C3%A9-que-precisas) incluida numa pergunta mais abrangente.

Comment: @Jacinto então abre um voto de pergunta duplicada. :)

Comment: Já alguém o fez. Mas eu achei por bem deixar-te ver se de facto a tua pergunta está contida na outra.

Comment: Fui eu. :p Acho que está contida, mas não está respondida adequadamente, falta a versão pt-PT acerca da regência com verbos infinitivos.

Comment: Eu interpretei isto "Porém o uso prático não é tão rigoroso; é bastante comum dizer preciso de falar" como aplicando-se a Portugal também. O que se pode argumentar é que em Portugal _precisar de falar_ é considerado correto. Vem no DACL sem qualquer advertência.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Brasil, **precisamos de alguma coisa** e **precisamos fazer alguma coisa**.
Portanto, **nós precisamos de** "um substantivo"  e **precisamos** "um verbo" e.g.

- Preciso de ajuda, de dinheiro, de alguém que me ame.
- Preciso ir agora, falar com você, encontrar meu passaporte.

@ANeves  Referia-me eu ao uso da preposição "de" quando o verbo precisar é usado em frases como "uma caixa não precisa ser quadrada". Nunca usamos a preposição "de" nesses casos ("precisa de ser").  Só os mineiros (nativos do Estado de Minas Gerais) falam assim.  Contudo, também usamos o verbo precisar como transitivo indireto: "eu preciso de uma informação, de instruções, de 50 Euros, etc... E até mesmo como intransitivo: "não precisa vocês virem tão cedo"  "eu trabalho porque preciso", "Não precisa, eu me viro sozinho."  Mas nunca ouvi alguém falar "eu preciso mais trabalho" e sim "de mais trabalho"

Comment: Já agora, frases sem complemento não levam "de" nem em Portugal, isso é um caso diferente: "não precisa de ajudar" vs "não precisa".

Comment: Tentei melhorar a pergunta; não tenho a certeza de ter conseguido.

Comment: Em "eu preciso ir", precisar não é intransitivo.

Comment: @Romildo Corrigido.

Comment: Em Portugal diríamos "precisam **de** fazer alguma coisa", "não precisam **de** vir tão cedo"... *mas* "trabalho porque preciso", "não precisas, eu desenrasco-me sozinho".

Comment: Pode-se usar precisar com um verbo que não esteja no infinitivo? «não precisa (sic) vocês **virem** tão cedo»?

Comment: @ANeves   Sim, usamos.  "Não precisa vocês fazerem isso" é de uso corrente na língua falada.  Ou, "não precisa que vocês façam isso".

Comment: Curioso. Em Portugal, não.