# Quando podemos usar artigos com adjetivos possessivos?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, português-europeu, uso-de-palavras, sintaxe

Enquanto aprendia português, vi o adjetivo possessivo ora precedido do artigo definitivo e ora não.

> a minha filha / minha filha

> o teu cabelo / teu cabelo

A escolha é aleatória?  Quando o artigo deve ser incluído?

Comment: O artigo é facultativo: “3a) Antes de pronomes possessivos, é outro caso facultativo. Podemos dizer “estamos a seu dispor” ou “ao seu dispor”; “esta é minha decisão” ou “a minha decisão”. O artigo definido só é obrigatório se o pronome possessivo estiver “sozinho” (substituindo um substantivo anteriormente citado): “Sua estratégia é melhor que a minha (estratégia)”” — http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/saiba-quando-devemos-usar-os-artigos-definidos.html.

Comment: Bem-vindo(a) ao site! Nalgumas situações, há PREFERÊNCIAS; ex,: em leis, contratos e afins é preferencial não usar o artigo quando facultativo. Em jornais, varia bastante, inclusive dentro duma mesma notícia. Na fala brasileira que conheço — sou do São Paulo  —, o comum é usar artigo quando facultativo, mas é totalmente possível ouvir sem.

Comment: O'Hara, bem-vindo ao site. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/366/is-there-a-general-rule-for-using-articles-before-proper-nouns/565#565); já lá tens uma resposta à tua; está é em inglês.